# Angular parent and child ngHide on ngClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So i have a progress bar, that when clicked will expand full screen w some stuff in it.  Im playing with angular trying stuff and i cant seem to get the close button toggle functionality working.  I have an ngClick on the parent to first show the close button which works fine! but then when i go to click the close button...nothing happens...when you click the close button it is supposed to hide the close button....in my controller i have the showClose variable set to true... think theres some scoping issue that im unaware of

here's a dummy version of whats happenening:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgMdRN?editors=101

```
<section ng-app="App">
  <div id="progress-container" ng-controller="ProgressCtrl">
      <div class="progress-bar" ng-click="showClose = false">
        <div class="close" ng-hide="showClose" ng-click="showClose = true" >Close</div>
      </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: The problem is that when you click in the inside div, the two ng-click get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the event propagation, which causes a child click event bubbles up to its parent containers. As a result you will see all the parent click event handlers get fired.

This should resolve your problem.

Script:

```
$scope.onClickClose = function(e){
  $scope.showClose = true;
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="progress-bar" ng-click="showClose = false">
        <div class="close" ng-hide="showClose" ng-click="onClickClose($event)" >Close</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: AHHHHH....i did that twenty times but i wasnt passing $event in the ngClick call....Thank you so much